# Comparing javascript date time and timestamp from PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, sql, date, datetime, timestamp

In PostgreSQL database, I have save in the timestamp column this value: **2013-03-15 08:50:00**.
My goal is to take this date from database and check, if the current time is less about 12 hours than the time from database.

For this purpose, I wanted to get the current time from `new Date()` and compare it with the date from database - but this doesn't work because of different time formats.

How could I do that and convert those times on the same (comparable) format?

Comment: I like using date.js - http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Unless it's absolutely necessary to get the time from the client, why not get it from the server using whatever application code you are using to query the db?

Answer (score 6):

var ds='2013-03-15 08:50:00';

without any timezone information you can't really tell what day it is.
Assuming your string is in UTC, you can use the Date constructor
if you replace the space with a 'T' and add a 'Z' at the end:

```
var ds='2013-03-15 08:50:00';

var day=new Date(ds.replace(' ','T')+'Z');

day.toUTCString()
```

**Fri, 15 Mar 2013 08:50:00 GMT**

You can write a Date parsing function that will parse ISO or sql formats,

which may be needed on some older browsers.

```
Date.fromISO= function(s){
    var day, tz,
    rx=/^(\d{4}\-\d\d\-\d\d([tT ][\d:\.]*)?)([zZ]|([+\-])(\d\d):(\d\d))?$/,
    p= rx.exec(s) || [];
    if(p[1]){
        day= p[1].split(/\D/);
        for(var i= 0, L= day.length;i<L;i++){
            day[i]= parseInt(day[i], 10) || 0;
        };
        day[1]-= 1;
        day= new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, day));
        if(!day.getDate()) return NaN;
            //adjust for time zone offset:
        if(p[5]){
            tz= (parseInt(p[5], 10)*60);
            if(p[6]) tz+= parseInt(p[6], 10);
            if(p[4]== '+') tz*= -1;
            if(tz) day.setUTCMinutes(day.getUTCMinutes()+ tz);
        }
        return day;
    }
    return NaN;
}
```

then call  **Date.fromISO('2013-03-15 08:50:00')**;